# C++ - Declarar múltiples variables en un bucle y utilizarlas para realizar cálculos

Tags: c++, array

Necesito hacer un programa [de consola] que obtenga el nombre completo de cinco personas, al igual que sus tres calificaciones para calcular su promedio.
En lugar de declarar variable por variable

```
string nom1, nom2 //...
int cal1, cal2 //...
```

quiero hacer un bucle for (o el que se requiera) para poder declarar cinco variables de nombre y tres variables de calificación y utilizarlas para mostrarlas en pantalla, al igual que para realizar cálculos.

Para ello, creé esta atrocidad para intentar hacerme tan siquiera una idea:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
//Actualizado porque tenía errores.

using namespace std;
int main()
{
        int lims = 5; //límite de estudiantes
        for (int nsx = 1; nsx < lims; ++nsx) //nsx: núm. de estudiante
        {
            cout << "Introduzca el nombre del " << nsx << "° alumno: ";
            string ns;
            cin >> ns;

            int limc = 3; //límite de calificaciones
            for (int cx = 1; cx < limc; ++cx) // cx: número de calificación
                cout << "Introduzca la calificación no. " << cx << " de " << ns << ": ";
                double c;
                cin >> c;

            switch (nsx) // Si se deja fuera del bucle for, no va a
                         // reconocer uno o más identificadores.
            {
            case 5:
                cout << "Alumno/a\tCalificacion\tPromedio";
                for (int nsx = 1, cx = 1; cx < limc, nsx < lims; ++nsx, ++cx)
            //Aquí quería hacer una tabla pero no logro hacer un formato adecuado :b
                    cout << "\n" << ns << "\t" << cx << ". " << c << "\n\t";
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Sin embargo, no he conseguido lo que esperaba. Cuando introduzco un nombre, me muestra "Introduce la calificación no. 1 de [nombre]: Introduce la calificación no. 2 de [nombre]: ". Esto puede ser porque está en el mismo bucle for, pero si lo separo no puedo mostrar los datos introducidos al final debido a que "no están definidos los identificadores".

¿Es posible lograr esto, o es algo que ni la magia puede lograr?

Comment: No sé utilizar bien los arrays :c

Había encontrado información e incluso un código de ejemplo, en esta página: [https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-declare-multiple-variables-in-C-inside-a-loop-so-that-at-any-iteration-a-new-variable-is-declared]

Comment: Para poder hacer lo que quieres, necesitas utilizar arreglos, o bien guardar la información en una cadena de texto, para que así solo utilices esas variables definidas y ya al final solo imprimes el texto.
Yo te recomiendo que utilices los arreglos, ya que estará mejor organizada la ingormación, además de que te ayudará a aprender algo nuevo, ya que por lo que veo eres nuevo en programación.

Comment: Gracias por responder ;w; llevo todo el día investigando sobre los arreglos y mi código está casi listo, sólo me falta calcular los promedios y mostrarlos en pantalla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás teniendo un problema con los bucles `for`.

Cuando se utiliza un bucle, todas las acciones que se van a realizar dentro de él deben estar dentro de llaves (`{ }`) a menos que el bucle `for` ejecute una sola accion por iteración.

En tu caso, tienes lo siguiente:

```
for (int cx = 1; cx < limc; ++cx) // cx: número de calificación
   cout << "Introduzca la calificación no. " << cx << " de " << ns << ": ";
   double c;
   cin >> c;
```

El programa aquí está interpretando que sólo debe iterar la primera de las tres líneas que deberían estar dentro del bucle; es decir, sólo está ejecutando la línea:

```
cout << "Introduzca la calificación no. " << cx << " de " << ns << ": ";
```

La ejecuta la primera vez y muestra: *"Introduce la calificación no. 1 de [nombre]:"*, y automáticamente vuelve a comenzar el ciclo porque al no haber llaves intepreta que debe ejecutar esa línea únicamente. Es por esto que acto seguido imprime en pantalla: *"Introduce la calificación no. 2 de [nombre]:*.

La solución a este problema es simplemente encerrar las tres líneas de código entre llaves, como se muestra a continuación:

```
for (int cx = 1; cx < limc; ++cx)
{
    cout << "Introduzca la calificaciÃ³n no. " << cx << " de " << ns << ": ";

    double c;

    cin >> c;
}
```

Ahora el bucle `for` se comportará tal y como debería.

## Otras cosas...

En tu función `main` te está faltando el retorno que, por defecto, es `return 0;` o `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.
Podrías, además, considerar trabajar este problema con funciones, ya que esto hará que tu código sea más legible, entendible y facilite el proceso de depuración del programa.

Por otro lado, dentro del `case 5` de tu `switch` estás teniendo un bucle `for` que está queriendo hacer uso de la variable `c` que fue declarada y usada en el bucle que ingresa las calificaciones de los alumnos. Cuando hayas corregido lo de las llaves, verás que el compilador te tirará un error precisamente allí, cuando quieres volver a usar la variable `c`, y esto se debe a que el alcance de una variable se ve limitado por las llaves en las que esté "encerrada".

Es decir, si tú haces lo siguiente:

```
for (int cx = 1; cx < limc; ++cx) // cx: nÃºmero de calificaciÃ³n
{
    cout << "Introduzca la calificaciÃ³n no. " << cx << " de " << ns << ": ";
    double c;
    cin >> c;
}
```

Fuera de este bucle no podrás acceder a la variable `c`, porque su alcance está delimitado por las llaves del bucle `for`, y una vez que este bucle finalice, no habrá forma de acceder a la variable `c`. Será eliminada.

Para solucionarlo, puedes considerar trabajar con un arreglo unidimensional de variables de tipo `float` o `int` para almacenar las calificaciones de cada estudiante, o también trabajar con estructuras que puedan tener como parámetros el nombre del alumno y un vector con sus notas. Esto ya es encarar para la programación orientada a objetos (**POO**), por si te interesa.

Finalmente, en cuanto al formato de la tabla, intenta darle un aspecto agradable con funciones como `setw()`. Eso te puede servir.

¡Espero haber sido de ayuda! Un saludo.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta :D Pues como mencioné en mi comentario casi no sé usar los arrays, sin embargo encontré este código y muestra un ejemplo de arrays:

[Código](https://pastebin.com/guT89nDV)

¿Puedo adaptar esto a lo que estoy haciendo?

PD: Dejo el sitio de donde obtuve este código ya que el que dejé en mi comentario no sirve: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-declare-multiple-variables-in-C-inside-a-loop-so-that-at-any-iteration-a-new-variable-is-declared)

Comment: ¡Me alegra que te haya servido! El código que dejas en el link de [aquí](https://pastebin.com/guT89nDV) puede ser implementado totalmente. Luego, para calcular el promedio, deberás hacer otro bucle ```for``` que sume todas las notas almacenadas en ese array, y divida el resultado final por la cantidad del notas que tiene el alumno. Si tienes dudas sobre cómo plantearlo, no tengo problema en ayudar. Intenta primero hacer un par de intentos tú revisando algunos tutoriales sobre arrays, que hay muchos. Seguro podrás solucionarlo una vez te hayas familiarizado con ellos. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Ok. Creo que ya casi termino el código. Pero el siguiente problema es que no consigo calcular el promedio de forma correcta; debido a que también debo declarar variables para cada promedio, realizar un cálculo no es posible ya que si lo hago usando el [código](https://pastebin.com/guT89nDV) que dejé en el comentario anterior, al mostrarlo la variable aparece como "1". Aquí dejo lo que llevo de [mi código](https://pastebin.com/dhpHxZ7b).

Comment: Como nota quiero agregar que si quito ```pr[prx] = 1``` el promedio se muestra como una especie de texto "encriptado", pues puede mostrar algo como "6.34647e-3171-49837e+1511.58428e-0761-23923e+1511.0367e-202", y si se deja como está se muestra "11111".

Comment: ¡Hola! Te dejo dos formas de resolver el problema que tienes que he desarrollado yo recién [aquí](https://pastebin.com/hNNiXd4f). Aclaro que son simplemente ideas para guiarte en la resolución del ejercicio. Allí tienes explicado en detalle el propósito del algoritmo, el funcionamiento de cada línea de código, pros y contras de cada algoritmo y recomendaciones personales para la solución de este problema. ¡Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Por otro lado, ese _"texto encriptado"_ que mencionas, es simplemente notación científica para números muy grandes. Te sugiero revisar lo que te envié y tener en cuenta las recomendaciones que dejé al final del archivo. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: (Pido disculpas por los errores de ortografía en los comentarios, lo he mandado sin revisar demasiado y se me han pasado por alto algunos...)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Akamai! No lo hubiera podido lograr sin ti :'D no sé cómo agradecerte

Comment: ¡Me alegra haberte ayudado y que hayas logrado solucionar el problema implementando lo que te pasé! Esto es un ejercicio que te afinará la mentalidad de programador. Ante cualquier duda, estoy dispuesto a ayudar. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Tengo un nuevo problema: al escribir términos no válidos (en el caso de nombres, si se introducen números y viceversa) el programa aún así los toma como válidos. ¿Qué puedo hacer para evitar esto? (PD: No sé mover a chat)

Comment: ¡Hola! Te recomiendo [este blog](https://www.javamexico.org/foros/java_standard_edition/como_validar_datos_de_tipo_int_o_string_en_java_usando_netbeans) y [este otro blog](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Java/1680183-ingresar-solo-letras-y-no-numeros.html). Allí tratan la validación de un String de formas distintas. Te dejo [aquí](https://pastebin.com/ZAsH8SrB) una implementación simple del código que aparece en [este comentario](https://www.javamexico.org/foros/java_standard_edition/como_validar_datos_de_tipo_int_o_string_en_java_usando_netbeans#comment-29904) del primer blog.

Comment: Si tienes problemas para validar otros tipos de datos, prueba buscar en internet **validar entrada [tipo de dato que quieres validar] en Java**. Hay muchos blogs y videos que tratan este tema. Si no encuentras nada, consúltame sin problemas. ¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucha desesperación y fallo y ensayo, conseguí terminar el código, siguiendo el [consejo](https://pastebin.com/hNNiXd4f) de @[Akamai](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/136531/akamai),

## y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#define lims 5 //límite de estudiantes (también se utiliza para limitar los promedios a calcular)
#define limc 3 //límite de calificaciones

using namespace std;

void check()
{
    if( cin.fail() ) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
}

int main()
{
        char acc = 162, deg = 248;
        int nsx, cx;
        double totc, prom;
        string *ns = new string[lims];  //Crear nuevas variables
        double *c = new double[limc];   //en el arreglo.

                //Estudiante
        for(nsx = 1; nsx <= lims; nsx++) //nsx: núm. de estudiante
            {
                do {
                cout << "Introduzca el nombre del " << nsx << deg << " estudiante: ";
                getline(cin, ns[nsx]);
                } while (ns[nsx] < "A" || ns[nsx] > "Z" && ns[nsx] < "a" || ns[nsx] > "z");
                check();
            }
                //Calificación      
            for(nsx = 1; nsx <= lims; nsx++)
            {
                for (cx = 1; cx <= limc; ++cx) // cx: número de calificación
                {
                 do {
                        cout << "Introduzca la calificaci"<<acc<<"n no. " << cx << " de " << ns[nsx] << ": ";
                        cin >> c[cx];
                        check();
                    } while (c[cx] < 0 || c[cx] > 10);
                    totc += c[cx];
                }
                prom = totc/limc;
                cout << "El promedio de " << ns[nsx] << " es: " << prom << endl;
                prom = 0;
                totc = 0;
             }
    return 0;
}
```

## Dando una explicación <strike>algo</strike> detallada de cómo funciona.

1. Para empezar se definen los límites, tanto de estudiantes (5) como de calificaciones (3).
2. Creamos una función void para reiniciar el campo de calificaciones en caso de que lo que se introduzca no sea válido.
3. Creamos nuestra función normal.
4. Declaramos variables de (*casi*) todos los sabores, empezando por

   - El acento "ó" y el signo de grados "°" debido a que al ejecutarse se muestran otros caracteres. Puedes revisar [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333514/mostrar-acentos-y-caracteres-unicode-en-visual-studio-2019/333520#333520) para entender a lo que me refiero, junto con una [tabla de caracteres ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/).
   - Los dos enteros que vamos a utilizar como contadores (*nsx* para los nombres y *cx* para las calificaciones).
   - Valores decimales para el total de las calificaciones (*totc*) y el promedio (*prom*).
   - Y las últimas dos variables (*ns* = nombre del estudiante | *c* = calificación) son las que se van a crear en el siguiente bucle.
5. Para: *nsx* (empezando desde 1 y terminando hasta el 5, "llenando el arreglo de estudiantes con sus nombres"):

   ---

   - Hacer:

     - Salida - "Introduzca el nombre del *nsx*° estudiante: "
     - Línea - Entrada de *ns*
   - Mientras *ns* tenga caracteres alfabéticos (**NO** se permiten signos ni números).

     ---
   - Para *nsx* (empezando desde 1 y terminando hasta el 5, contando para cada alumno sin alterar variables):

     ---
   - Y para *cx* (empezando desde 1 y terminando hasta el 3, llenando el arreglo de calificaciones con sus respectivos valores):
   - Hacer:

     - Salida - "Introduzca la calificación no. *cx* de *ns*: "
     - Entrada - *c*

       > //El motivo por el cual uno es de línea (*getline*) y otro es de entrada (*cin*) es debido a que, al momento de introducir espacios en *ns*, ocasionamos errores en el programa que evitan que se introduzca una calificación.
   - Mientras *c* sea un número mayor a 0 y/o menor a 10 (**NO** se permiten signos ni letras).

     ---
   - Se calcula el *totc*, que es igual a la suma de las tres calificaciones introducidas.

     ---

¿Aún estás llevando la cuenta?

6. Se calcula el *prom*, que es igual al *totc* entre el límite de calificaciones (3).

   > Se da a conocer el promedio de uno de nuestros estudiantes:
7. Salida - "El promedio de *ns* es: *prom*"
8. Para terminar, se reinician los valores tanto del total como del promedio, ya que si se dejan como están se van a sumar a los próximos valores que vayamos a introducir de nuestros siguientes estudiantes.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que este tipo de publicaciones tenga cabida en el sitio ... Nos centramos en preguntas y respuestas **concretas**. [He llevado esta publicación a meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4626/19610) para que la comunidad decida.

Comment: ¿Es muy específico el caso? ._.'

Comment: Considera que tal vez a lo que se refiere Trauma es que tu respuesta solo puede aplicar a tu caso en específico y no a una duda generalizada que pueda ayudar a un público amplio; es decir que alguien mas que consulte debería tener exactamente el mismo ejercicio y problema que tu

Comment: Tal vez lo hice muy específico al imponer valores y el contexto en el que está mi duda, pues yo quería saber cómo utilizar variables declaradas en un bucle (porque es fácil encontrar cómo declararlas); no sólo para realizar cálculos sino para otras acciones que pueda requerir el programador.