# Mostrar acentos y caracteres Unicode en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Se tiene un código como el siguiente:

```
#include<wchar.h>
#include<locale>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    cout << "La mejor calificación de Elliot es de 8.";
    return 0;
}
```

al compilarlo y ejecutarlo en **Visual Studio 2019** se muestra como posible salida:

> La mejor calificaciÃ³n de Elliot es de 8.

Sin embargo, en versiones anteriores (como VS15) se muestra como salida:

> La mejor calificación de Elliot es de 8.

Tal vez me he perdido de algo o estoy haciendo algo mal. ¿Hay alguna de mostrar los acentos en la versión más reciente de Visual Studio?

Comment: Tal vez éste [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/c%C3%B3mo-imprimir-caracteres-con-acentos-en-c) pueda servirte, a mi me sirvió la respuesta de @Victor Alvarado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basándome en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59796/154404) del post que te puse en los comentarios, podrías usar algo como:

```
printf("La mejor calificaci%cn de Elliot es de 8.", 162);
```

Para usar `cout` podrías declarar antes el caracter:

```
char c = 162;
cout << "La mejor calificaci"<<c<<"n de Elliot es de 8.";
```

> Códigos:
>
> á: 160 é: 130 í: 161 ó: 162 ú: 163 Á: 181 É: 144 Í: 214 Ó: 224 Ú: 23
>   ñ: 164 Ñ: 165

Comment: Voy a dejar esta [tabla de caracteres](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) para más información, borro mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Llevo un par de horas peleandome con el mismo problema que skidd10pp
Soy neófito en VS 2019, pero despues de darle vueltas, y parece increible, la solucion:

1. Crear proyecto C++ VACIO, insisto VACIO .. no partir de la base del "hola mundo"
2. Este codigo "normal" me ha funcionado

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   #include <locale.h>

   int main() {

       // Establecer el idioma a español
       setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

       printf("Hóla ñoña\n");
       std::cout << "Hóla ñoña\n";
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Te traigo la solución.

Lo bajo de una forma simple mediante este código:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <locale.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {

        // Para Linux - Usa locale.h
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish");

        // Para Windows - Usa Windows.h
        SetConsoleCP(1252);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);

        return 0;

    }
```

¡Saludos!