# ¿Como imprimir en consola caracteres latinos en C++?

Tags: c++

Al intentar imprimir en consola algún carácter latino como tildes o acentos, introduce signos raros en ese carácter. ¿Hay alguna función especial para evitar esto?

Comment: ¿Te sirve este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333514/mostrar-acentos-y-caracteres-unicode-en-visual-studio-2019)?

Answer (score 4):

Debes usar [setlocale](https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) para especificar la localización del sistema especificado:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    std::cout << "¿Por qué los perros corren tan rápido?" << std::endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribucion, te sugerimos agregar una explicaciòn de lo que realzia el còdigo, Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Adentro del main pon:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
```

Comment: Deberías indicar qué es lo que hace esa función y por qué o cómo soluciona el problema. Las respuestas que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.